# Differential equation with initial conditions problem: how do we solve $yy'' - 2(y')^2 - y^2 = 0$?

Tags: differential

I have problem with solving following equation with initial conditions:
$$y*y''-2(y')^2-y^2=0 $$
$$y(0)=1; y'(0)=0 $$
The problem is that i've tried substitution $ u(y)=y' $
and I end up with $$u'*u-2u^2/y =y $$ which is basically bernouli equation.
I've done z sub so that: $z(y)=u^2$
and got equation $$z'-4z/y=2y $$
I solved that  and got (with my initial condition ) $z=y^4-y^2 $ and that implies $ u^2=y^4-y^2 $
I have no idea what should be next step
Any help appreciated !

Comment: it does not depend on 3  variables

Comment: both equations after u sub are dependend on y

Comment: but y is a function of x

Comment: it is u[y(x)]  .

Comment: look at my profile, i asked simmilar question and somebody solved it using u=y' sub

Comment: u can use u(y)=y' sub and u get that y''=u'*y'=u'*u,(
derivative of a compound function) u can use also u(x)=y but not in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
yy'' - 2(y')^{2} - y^{2} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y''}{y} - \frac{(y')^{2}}{y^{2}} - \left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)^{2} - 1 = 0
\end{align*}
Moreover, we do also have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{y''}{y} - \frac{(y')^{2}}{y^{2}} = \frac{y''y - (y')^{2}}{y^{2}} = \left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'
\end{align*}

Hence, if we make the substitution $y' = uy$, we obtain the following ODE
\begin{align*}
u' - u^{2} - 1 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow u' = u^{2} + 1 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{u'}{u^{2}+1} = 1
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: YES. thanks a lot